# Vectorized access to array

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

Is there a way for vectorized to access to overlapping segments of an array?
Or whats the fastest way to do this ?

minimal sample with for loop

```
A=rand(5);
B=rand(10,5);
m=6;
for idx=1:m
    C(idx)=sum(sum((A(:,:)-B(idx: end-(m+1-idx),:)).^2));
end
```

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your indices, B(10,:) is never read.

Comment: When your data starts becoming huge, it becomes faster to calculate correlation using the FFT than direct computation.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `B(idx: end-(m+1-idx)+1,:)` instead?

Comment: Any feedback on the comment made earlier or on the posted solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that performs vectorized accesses using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) & [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) -

```
% Size parameters
m = size(A,1);
n = size(B,1);

% Extended version of B, i.e. "B(idx: end-(m+1-idx)+1,:)" across all iterations
B_ext = B(bsxfun(@plus,(1:m)',0:n-m),:);

% Perform broadcasted subtraction against A and finally squared summations
C = sum(sum(bsxfun(@minus,reshape(B_ext,m,n-m+1,[]),permute(A,[1,3,2])).^2,1),3)
```